# How to overwrite multiple outputted lines from a bash script into the terminal

Tags: bash

I have a kubernetes command `kubectl get pods` which prints to the terminal this output

```
 NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
redis-cart-74594bd569-ffrhk   1/1     Running   0          40m
```

I want this command to run repeatedly every two seconds in a bash script.
However, I want the output to overwrite the last input.

Currently, I can get it to overwrite one line (the first outputted line) by using a carriage return. But it doesn't overwrite the second line.

How can I overwrite previously outputted text from my bash script?

By script looks like this atm

```
#!/bin/bash

variable=$(kubectl get pods)

while true
do
    variable=$(kubectl get pods)
    echo -ne "$variable" "\r"
    sleep 2
done
exit
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do that if you have available commands such us `watch`.

Comment: I didn't realise the ```watch``` commands existence, looking into it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `clear` command to the loop:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

variable=$(kubectl get pods)

while true
do
    variable=$(kubectl get pods)
    clear
    echo -ne "$variable" "\r"
    sleep 2
done
```

But, you can use `watch` or `-w` to get a similar result without a special script.

Answer (score 1):

try `watch`to refresh output ...

```
watch kubectl get pods
```

To end the process you can use `CTRL+C` or look for the process via `ps` or `pgrep`and send a **SIGINT** like `pgrep watch kubectl | xargs kill -1`.